# What is the use of immutable.js while using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability, react-redux, immutable.js

This is something I'am not getting right.

While using redux, in reducers we use the spread operator.

For e.g.

`{...state,data : action.payload,fetching:false}`

That is a new state object is created, rather than mutating the correct state right? (Please correct me if i'am wrong)

In such cases what is the use of immutableJS ??
It performs the same action as mentioned above right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the example you have shown is creating a new object and not mutating the state.  It is fine for many cases, so if you don't feel that ImmutableJS is going to add anything for you, don't use it.

ImmutableJS was more useful before the spread operator was in common use in ES6 (I believe it is technically [still only a proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread)).  If you are not using ES6, then the alternative is to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which can get very messy, very quickly, especially with more nested structures.

ImmutableJS is still useful if you need to modify a single node deep within the state tree, but if this is the case, you can generally get around it by structuring the data in a different way.

Comment: Yea there are mixed benefits to using it. I would say it's not so messy if you have a normalized data structure, and at that point Immutable loses some of the benefits of an easy API to make deeper changes as you aren't going to have deep trees. However that aside, I still believe Immutable forces you to be immutable in all your data changes, and ensures that other developers must be too, whilst using a convenient API. I personally would recommend it

Comment: Yeah, that's a great point.  I'm a big believer in only using libraries when it makes sense to, so if the codebase is shared then, in my opinion, enforcing immutability would be a reasonable reason to use it.

Comment: "and at that point Immutable loses some of the benefits of an easy API to make deeper changes as you aren't going to have deep trees" @Glitch100 Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Well if you normalize your state you can potentially end up with a shallower state tree. See: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

That aside I would still recommend using Immutable if only for the fact it forces you to use and think in an immutable fashion

Answer (score 1):

When you have a simple flat state, you can easily manage it without extra libraries.

But let's consider something more complex, like the following

```
{
  users: {
     123: {
       name: 'John',
       lastName: 'Doe'
     },
     345: {
       name: 'Bob',
       lastName: 'Jack'
     }
     ....
  }
}
```

If you want to update a name for some user, it will be not so trivial

```
return {  
  ...state,
  users: {
    ...state.users,
    [action.userId]: {
       ...state.users[action.userId],
       name: action.newName
    }
  }
```

Pretty much code, isn't it? At this moment, you may want to look for another solution and immutable.js may help you do the same with one line:

```
state.setIn(['users', action.userId, 'name'], action.newName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Making your state immutable ensures you that the state will not get modified outside of flux-flow. In very complex structures with a lot of levels and props being passed around it, it prevents the state from being mutated accidentally.